# How to delay a ScheduledExecutorService?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a `ScheduledExecutorService` that executes a task periodically:

```
executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
```

On a specific event, I want to reset or delay time for the schedule. How can or should this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to the `Future<?>` returned by that method.

```
Future<?> taskHandle = scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate
```

Then call `cancel` on it and schedule it again at a different rate.

```
taskHandle.cancel(false);
taskHandle = scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate
```